# Adding input field Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I tried to make a function which will add input field using TypeScript in Angular. Look at this screen.

[image]

I am getting correct field view in JSON but not in actual screen. I don't know how to change it. I tried many solutions but didn't got succeed.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="margin-20">
        <h4>Add customer</h4>
      </div>
      <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
          <small *ngIf="!myForm.controls.name.valid" class="text-danger">
            Name is required (minimum 5 characters).
          </small>
        </div>
        <!--addresses-->
        <div formArrayName="addresses">
          <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Address {{i + 1}}</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="myForm.controls.addresses.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label>street</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street">
                <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.addresses.controls[i].controls.street.valid" class="text-danger">
                  Street is required
                </small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label>postcode</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
              </div>
              <div *ngFor="let answer of myForm.controls.answers.controls; let 
    i=index" class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                  <label>answer</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
     formControlName="answer">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="margin-20">
                <a (click)="addAnswers()" style="cursor: default">
                  Add another answer +
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="margin-20">
          <a (click)="addAddress()" style="cursor: default">
            Add another address +
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="margin-20">
          <a (click)="initA()" style="cursor: default">
            Add another address +
          </a>
        </div>




        <div class="margin-20">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
     [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="margin-20">
          <div>myForm details:-</div>
          <pre>Is myForm valid?: <br>{{myForm.valid | json}}</pre>
          <pre>form value: <br>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray,  FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Customer } from './customer.interface';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
            addresses: this._fb.array([
                this.initAddress(),
            ]),
          answers: this._fb.array([
            this.initAnswers(),
          ])
        });
    }


  initA() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      addresses: this._fb.array([
        this.initAddress(),
      ]),
      answers: this._fb.array([
        this.initAnswers(),
      ])
    });
  }


    initAddress() {
        return this._fb.group({
            street: ['', Validators.required],
            postcode: [''],
            answer: ['']
        });
    }

    addAddress() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
        control.push(this.initAddress());
    }

    removeAddress(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }

  initAnswers() {
    return this._fb.group({
      answer: ['']
    });
  }

     addAnswers() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['answers'];
    control.push(this.initAnswers());
  }

  removeAnswers(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['answers'];
    control.removeAt(i);
  }

    save(model: Customer) {
        // call API to save
        // ...
        console.log(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks a bit like you're using a modified demo to show the current Angular data as JSON. Any chance that would be easy to put into a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/), so we could see the problem in action?

Comment: Off the bat, it looks at least like there's disagreement between your TypeScript structure and your template; e.g. "answers" is an array of groups in your TS, but there's no mention of that array or groups in the template. Similarly, "answers" is nested within "addresses" in your template, but on the same level in your TS (shown in your example JSON data as well)